# Map application isn't updating location until Google maps location has been updated

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, location

I get the current location in my app only after the google maps is updated first, whereas if I don't update the Google maps, my app isn't able to get the current location.Here's my Java code:

MapsActivity.java

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
    View.OnClickListener{

//Our Map
private GoogleMap mMap;

//To store longitude and latitude from map
private double longitude;
private double latitude;

//Buttons
private ImageButton buttonSave;
private ImageButton buttonCurrent;
private ImageButton buttonView;

//Google ApiClient
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //Initializing googleapi client
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    //Initializing views and adding onclick listeners
    buttonSave = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
    buttonCurrent = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonCurrent);
    buttonView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonView);
    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonCurrent.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    googleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

//Getting current location
private void getCurrentLocation() {
    mMap.clear();
    //Creating a location object
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    if (location != null) {
        //Getting longitude and latitude
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();

        //moving the map to location
        moveMap();
    }
}

//Function to move the map
private void moveMap() {
    //String to display current latitude and longitude
    String msg = latitude + ", "+longitude;

    //Creating a LatLng Object to store Coordinates
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    //Adding marker to map
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng) //setting position
            .draggable(true) //Making the marker draggable
            .title("Current Location")); //Adding a title

    //Moving the camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    //Animating the camera
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    //Displaying current coordinates in toast
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    getCurrentLocation();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
    //Clearing all the markers
    mMap.clear();

    //Adding a new marker to the current pressed position
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .draggable(true));
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    //Getting the coordinates
    latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
    longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

    //Moving the map
    moveMap();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonCurrent){
        getCurrentLocation();
        moveMap();
    }}}
```

Here Is My Manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.takecare">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here Is My App Gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thy these lines of code you write  wrong

this code for get current lat and long data

```
longitude = location.getLongitude();
latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

and you set this data to set on map

```
mMap = googleMap;
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-34, 151);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
```

after update your location you are going to set this location

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(latLng)
        .draggable(true));

where as your data is on latLng   -34, 151
```

thats by you are not getting updated data on map just get latest data by using these lines of code

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLongitude(),location.getLatitude());
```

I have not checked your gradle or manifest please check at your end.

may be this code will help you );